# Trying to figure out how to stop a CSS animation on my hamburger menu after the sidebar opens on a site I am working on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I am wanting to do is to have a hamburger menu that slightly bounces, which it is doing by using CSS animation as you can see from the CSS code below. Then, I would like for the hamburger menu to stop bouncing once the sidebar toggle is initiated which is created using JQuery code below.

What I have tried is the CSS **:not()**, but had no luck with that method.

Anyway, any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I currently have:

```js
function sidebarToggleFunction() {
    document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("sidebartoggle");
    });
}

sidebarToggleFunction()
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 100rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    opacity: .75;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
    z-index: 200;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*
    Hamburger Menu Bounce
    ---------------------
    Description: - Up/Down animation
*/

.hamburger-menu {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

.sidebartoggle .hamburger-menu {
    right: 33rem;
    background-color: #555;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 100rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    opacity: .75;
}

@keyframes scale {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}

@keyframes movebanner {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(40rem) rotateY(-20deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.sidebar {
    width: 40rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -40rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: right 0.5s;
}

.sidebartoggle .sidebar {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
        <section class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-hamburger-menu">
                <div class="shm-line line-1"></div>
                <div class="shm-line line-2"></div>
                <div class="shm-line line-3"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a class to stop the animation once the menu is click:

```
.hamburger-menu.stop {
  animation-name: none;
}
```

and in Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').classList.toggle('stop');
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
function sidebarToggleFunction() {
    document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
     document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').classList.toggle('stop');
        document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("sidebartoggle");
    });
    
   
}

sidebarToggleFunction()
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 100rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    opacity: .75;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
    z-index: 200;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*
    Hamburger Menu Bounce
    ---------------------
    Description: - Up/Down animation
*/

.hamburger-menu {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}
.hamburger-menu.stop {
 animation-name: none;
}


@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

.sidebartoggle .hamburger-menu {
    right: 33rem;
    background-color: #555;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 100rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    opacity: .75;
}

@keyframes scale {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}

@keyframes movebanner {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(40rem) rotateY(-20deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.sidebar {
    width: 40rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -40rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: right 0.5s;
}

.sidebartoggle .sidebar {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
        <section class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-hamburger-menu">
                <div class="shm-line line-1"></div>
                <div class="shm-line line-2"></div>
                <div class="shm-line line-3"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This did it for me! I am just starting out with web development and your expertise is invaluable.

Comment: Glad to help, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout to remove the class.

Comment: could you give an example of this, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery then just add an animated class to your hamburger menu, attach the animation CSS to that class and toggle it.

Working version: https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/pk10t632/6/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hamburger-menu animated">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
        </div>
        <section class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-hamburger-menu">
                <div class="shm-line line-1"></div>
                <div class="shm-line line-2"></div>
                <div class="shm-line line-3"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS (just change the existing CSS rule to add the animated class):

```
.hamburger-menu.animated {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    animation: bounce 1s  infinite alternate;
}
```

JQuery:

```
function sidebarToggleFunction() {
    document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("sidebartoggle");
        $('.hamburger-menu').toggleClass('animated');
    });
}

sidebarToggleFunction()
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason it did not work for me after I added my sidebar class and styled it.